# R: correct implementation of price in conjoint analysis using support.CEs

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the 'support.CEs' package in R to construct a questionnaire for a conjoint analysis.
At first I ran the following code:

```
    # Create questionnaire
## Define attributes/levels
atts <- list(price=c("489","809","999", "1259"),
screensize=c("4.7","5.4", "6.1", "6.7"),
camera=c("Standard","Good", "Very good", "Excellent"))

## Create design 
des <- rotation.design(attribute.names=atts,
            nalternatives=2,
            nblocks=1,
            randomize=TRUE,
            seed=345)
```

This resulted in one option containing no information:

```
Question 16

 alt.1 alt.2

 screensize "6.7" "6.7"

 camera "Standard" "Standard"

 price "809" "999"
```

I don't want my questionnaire to have these kind of questions since everyone will choose the lowest price one given that the other options are equal.

I tried to implement price as an ordinal variable like this:

```
price <- factor(c("489","809","999", "1259"), order = TRUE,
                  levels = c("489","809","999", "1259"))
```

But this gave me the exact same result.

Giving in price as a numeric variable resulted in no change as well.

I have looked into the support.CEs documentation, but this didn't help me either.

Does anyone have some more information on how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no direct way to achieve this, however using `tidyverse` we can wrangle the questionnaire data to get it to look like what you want:

```r
# get the list of questions
des$alternatives %>%
    # turn into a single tibble
    bind_rows %>%
    # nest by question number
    nest_by(QES) %>%
    # get the nested column
    .$data %>%
    # map over the each entry keeping only those with different camera types
    imap_dfr( ~ if(length(unique(.x$camera))>1) .x  else tibble()) %>% 
    # split the resulting tibble into a list
    split(., .$ALT) %>%
    # add new QES number ## IMPORTANT
    map(~ .x %>% mutate(QES=row_number())) -> des$alternatives

# reset the number of question to the actual selected questions ## IMPORTANT
des$design.information$nquestions <- nrow(des$alternatives[[1]])

# get the questionnaire
questionnaire(des)
```

```
Block 1 
 
Question 1 
           alt.1  alt.2     
screensize "5.4"  "4.7"     
camera     "Good" "Standard"
QES        "1"    "1"       

Question 2 
           alt.1  alt.2      
screensize "6.1"  "4.7"      
camera     "Good" "Excellent"
QES        "2"    "2"        

Question 3 
           alt.1       alt.2 
screensize "6.1"       "6.1" 
camera     "Excellent" "Good"
QES        "3"         "3"   

Question 4 
           alt.1       alt.2      
screensize "6.7"       "4.7"      
camera     "Excellent" "Very good"
QES        "4"         "4"        

Question 5 
           alt.1       alt.2 
screensize "4.7"       "4.7" 
camera     "Very good" "Good"
QES        "5"         "5"   

Question 6 
           alt.1       alt.2     
screensize "6.7"       "6.1"     
camera     "Very good" "Standard"
QES        "6"         "6"       

Question 7 
           alt.1  alt.2      
screensize "4.7"  "6.7"      
camera     "Good" "Excellent"
QES        "7"    "7"        

Question 8 
           alt.1      alt.2 
screensize "6.1"      "5.4" 
camera     "Standard" "Good"
QES        "8"        "8"   

Question 9 
           alt.1       alt.2     
screensize "4.7"       "5.4"     
camera     "Excellent" "Standard"
QES        "9"         "9"       

Question 10 
           alt.1      alt.2      
screensize "6.7"      "5.4"      
camera     "Standard" "Excellent"
QES        "10"       "10"       

Question 11 
           alt.1      alt.2      
screensize "5.4"      "6.1"      
camera     "Standard" "Very good"
QES        "11"       "11"
```